# How to correctly define function on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, function, delphi-7

I have this function declaration and implementation

```
public
function AddWordReference(wordId,translateId:Longint):Longint;
{***}
function AddWordReference(wordId,translateId:Longint):Longint;
begin
try
 if((wordId <> -1) OR (translateId <> -1))  Then
 begin
 DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.AppendRecord([nil,wordId,translateId]);
 DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.Last;
 AddWordReference := DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger;
 end;
Except
ShowMessage('Error wirh adding reference');
AddWordReference := -1;
end;
AddWordReference := -1;
end;
```

I have this error:

```
[Error] AddFormUnit.pas(34): Unsatisfied forward or external declaration: 'TForm2.AddWordReference'
```

How to fix this error ?

Comment: To make your work easier, after you define your function in the interface part, press Ctrl-Shift-C to auto define the function correctly in the implementation part.

Comment: @Justmade, thanks for the shortcut :)

Comment: @Justmade, if you don't use Delphi XE2 :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a member of your `TForm2` class, so in the implementation section, you have to declare it as `TForm2.AddWordReference` instead of just `AddWordReference`.  And then inside the method itself, you should be assigning your return value to the compiler's `Result` variable instead of the `AddWordReference` method name:

```
public
  function AddWordReference(wordId, translateId: Longint): Longint;
```

.

```
function TForm2.AddWordReference(wordId, translateId: Longint): Longint;
begin
  Result := -1;
  try
    if (wordId <> -1) OR (translateId <> -1) then
    begin
      DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.AppendRecord([nil, wordId, translateId]);
      DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.Last;
      Result := DataModule1.TranslateDictionary.FieldByName('Id').AsInteger;
    end;
  except
    ShowMessage('Error wirh adding reference');
  end;
end;
```